# what is the right way to change label of a kubernetes node without using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes

Assuming kubectl is not setup locally, you having full access to SSH into nodes.
Is there any local commands that can be issued from the slaves nodes to edit the label ?
Can I use kubernetes patch but not being triggered from kubectl ?
or should I edit kubelet file(label section) and restart kubelet service ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a patch API call directly. Pass `--v=8` to kubectl to see the API calls it is making for any command.